# FailoverClientConnectionFactory is not threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-integration

I had code working with `TcpNioClientConnectionFactory` and it has been working fine. Until recently when I made change so that the TCP client perform failover in case of down time of server by using `FailoverClientConnectionFactory` and it starts to return me response for different request, even for single `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` provided to the Failover factory.

My code is using `@MessagingGateway` and the method is wrapped using `CompletableFuture` however even without `CompletableFuture` it still return wrong response (most of the time).

The log file is showing

> ERROR o.s.i.i.t.TcpOutboundGateway - Cannot correlate response - no pending reply

I can always reproduce this issue using IT test.

Please help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with 100 concurrent threads with `single-use` true or false. What version of Spring Integration? Also, please edit your question to show the gateway and connection factory configuration.

Comment: The underlaying connection factories passed to FailoverClientConnectionFactory are CachingClientConnectionFactories. I know there was issue with CachingClientConnectionFactories, but my test was working with CachingClienConnectionFactory. The spring integration version is 4.1.4. I tried 4.1.5 but the issue is still happening. I'll update the question with the config

Comment: This probably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459804/spurious-error-cannot-correlate-response-no-pending-reply-using-tcpoutboundg?noredirect=1#comment49001543_30459804, but my code seems to be ok with `CachingClientConnectionFactory`. Only when a combination of `TcpOutboundGateway` with `CachingClientConnectionFactory` and `FailoverClientConnectionFactory`, then the issue appear.

Comment: Could be; I was doing some work for 4.2 the other day and found some issues with the FailoverCCF [it hasn't been merged to master yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1473) but I'd be interested to know if it solves your issue (you'd have to build from that branch); it should be merged in the next few days and will be available as 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. If it solves your issue, we can backport part of that change to 4.1.x.

Comment: What's the branch name?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration.git`, `git checkout --track INT-3654`, `./gradlew install -x test` will install SI 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT into your local maven repo.

Comment: Apparently the issue is on my configuration. I configured `CachingClientCF` with `FailoverClientCF` as underlying CF. It is supposed to be `FailoverClientCF` with `CachingClientCF`. Thanks Gary for trying to help me.